# How to execute PHP in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to run a PHP script in a Wordpress SFTP but I don't know how to do it. What the script does is join 2 CSV files into one, but I don't know how to execute it (It's something apart from the web page as such, I'm using SFTP to import some Qualtrics CSV). How do I run it?

```
<?php

$outputFile = 'General.csv';
$outputHandle = fopen($outputFile, 'w');

$csvFiles = ['Evaluacion1.csv', 'Evaluacion2.csv'];
foreach ($csvFiles as $csvFile) {
    $inputHandle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    
    if ($csvFile !== $csvFiles[0]) {
        fgetcsv($inputHandle);
    }
    
    while ($data = fgetcsv($inputHandle)) {
        fputcsv($outputHandle, $data);
    }
    
    fclose($inputHandle);
}

fclose($outputHandle);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For basic functionality of triggering specific code, recommend placing your code into an mu-plugin, and gating with a query parameter. Something like this (untested):

`wp-content/mu-plugins/combine-csv-files.php`

```php
<?php

if ( ! isset( $_GET['combine-csv'] ) ) {
    return;
}

$outputFile = 'General.csv';
$outputHandle = fopen($outputFile, 'w');

$csvFiles = ['Evaluacion1.csv', 'Evaluacion2.csv'];
foreach ($csvFiles as $csvFile) {
    $inputHandle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    
    if ($csvFile !== $csvFiles[0]) {
        fgetcsv($inputHandle);
    }
    
    while ($data = fgetcsv($inputHandle)) {
        fputcsv($outputHandle, $data);
    }
    
    fclose($inputHandle);
}

fclose($outputHandle);
```

With this you can execute the code on demand by adding `?combine-csv` to any URL: `https://example.com/?combine-csv`. If it's sensitive, you'll want to move into the WordPress admin along with a nonce check.